# PHP function with two parentheses: calc(1)(2)

Tags: javascript, php

**JavaScript**:

```js
function calc(x) {
  return function(y) {
     return x + y;
  };
}

console.log(calc(1)(2));
```

This will return `3`.

I tried the same with **PHP**:

```
function calc($x) {
    return function($y) { 
        return $x + $y; 
    };
}

echo calc(1)(2);
```

This will return `2`. 
And I get an E_NOTICE:

> E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: x -- at line 4

Why is the variable `x` undefined? Is it because that wouldn't work with PHP or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php see example 3, "Inheriting variables from the parent scope"

Comment: Why not just use two arguments? `function calc($x, $y){ return $x+$y; }` You're function is complex for no reason.

Comment: @zatyh because it's a gateway to leveraging way more powerful functional programming paradigms. At the very least, you'd be able to do something like `$arrayOne.map(add(3))` and `$arrayTwo.map(add(15))` instead of re-writing the same basic add functionality each time. Now let's imagine that you assigned both of those callbacks in variables because you need to do both regularly. That saved you even more code. Now let's say these callbacks are called `addShippingTax` and `addDutyTax`. You only need one function that makes your code easier to maintain and easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's called a closure :

http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
function calc($x) {
    return function($y) use($x){ 
        return $x + $y; 
    };
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: PHP doesn't have Closures, they are Anonymous Functions. Closures as a concept enclose around the scope in which they are defined, the lack of which is the source of OP's issue. PHP just inexplicably named the internal object created by defining an anonymous function "Closure", probably so that pedants like me have something to do with their time.