# Specific php functionality

Tags: php

My team lead some time ago asked this question, which I didn't understood:

```
Implement function calc()
Please, implement function calc so code  below works:

$sum = function($a, $b)  { return $a + $b; };
calc(5)(3)(2)($sum);    // 10
calc(1)(2)($sum);       // 3
calc(2)(3)('pow');      // 8
```

So, can someone explain me what is it, and maybe some link on this functionality

Comment: This is close: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52449908/2943403

Comment: This looks like a job for anonymous recursion to me -- I don't support the closing of this page.

Comment: Even though the marked question seems close enough, the passing of a callback as last argument makes this one a bit different / more challenging. Not sure this should have been closed.

Comment: @Progrock Don't think that'll work for more than 2 args though. https://3v4l.org/rsqd1 should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will satisfy your example use:

```
<?php
function calc($input)
{
    static $args = [];

    if(is_callable($input)) {
        $carry  = array_shift($args);
        $result = array_reduce($args, $input, $carry);
        $args = []; // Clear the arguments.

        return $result;
    } else {
        $args[] = $input; // Add arguments to the stack.

        return __FUNCTION__;
    }
}

$sum = function($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
};

echo
    calc(5)(3)(2)($sum), "\n",
    calc(1)(2)($sum), "\n",
    calc(2)(3)('pow'), "\n",
    calc(5)(2)(2)('pow');
```

Output:

```
10
3
8
625
```

Explanation:

When `calc` is called with a single argument (that is not a [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)),  the input is pushed to an array and the name of the function, here 'calc', is returned.
`calc(2)(3)` will add 2 to the [static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) array (this will persist between subsequent function calls), and return the function name.  So this becomes `calc(3)`, where the previous call has the side effect of storing 2 in `$args`.

If the argument passed is a callable.  [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) will pass pairs of arguments from `$args` left to right to the callable, seeding subsequent calls with the result of each iteration.

`array_reduce([1,2,3], 'pow', $initial)` is similar to the following:

```
$result = pow($initial, 1);
$result = pow($result, 2);
$result = pow($result, 3);
```

However we need to use [array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to remove the first item from the `$args` array as a seed for the first iteration of the `pow` call:

So that becomes `array_reduce([2,3], 'pow', 1)`.

We then clear the argument list, otherwise subsequent calls to `calc` will use these arguments again, and the result of the `array_reduce` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

You could have it as a `calc` function that takes a value and:

- if it's a not a function, adds it to a buffer array, then return the function itself,
- if it's a function, calls that function subsequently on every value of that buffer.

> So if we take `calc(6)(3)($sum)`:
>
> - `calc(6)` call will add `6` to the buffer array then return the `calc` function,
> - `(3)` will therefore pass `3` as a param to that same `calc` function that was just returned, therefore adding `3`  to the buffer and returning the `calc`
>     function again,
> - finally, `($sum)` will generate a call to that `$sum` function, passing it every value from the buffer (therefore, `3` then `6`), reducing it into the final result.

Code:

```
function calc($value_or_function, array $buffer = [])
{   
  // If the argument is callable (a function), check that the buffer has
  // at least one value and call this function subsequently on each value, 
  // reducing it into a final value
  if (is_callable($value_or_function)) {
    if (count($buffer) === 0) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Not enough parameters.');
    }
    return array_reduce(array_slice($buffer, 1), $value_or_function, $buffer[0]);
  }

  // Otherwise (not a callable arg), add it to the buffer and return the
  // function itself so that its result can be chain-called
  return static function ($otherValue) use ($buffer, $value_or_function) {
    return calc($otherValue, array_merge($buffer, [$value_or_function]));
  };
}

// Example usage
$sum = function ($a, $b)  { return $a + $b; };
echo calc(5)(4)(3)($sum), PHP_EOL;
echo calc(5)(2)(2)('pow');
```

Additional notes:

- this is a decent exercise but probably a bad idea to have in a real codebase, this is quite unintuitive, the function does too many things, doesn't have strictly typed params, etc.,
- those inline comments are a bit much for real code (they're that detailed for explanation purposes).

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/AoKJO**

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't allow calling `calc` multiple times independently, such as `$calc = calc(5)(4); echo calc(2)(5)('pow'); echo $calc($sum);` - This wasn't what was asked but should still be known.

Comment: @Padarom Absolutely right. I didn't like the `static` variable anyway so I've just edited it to a version that should be safer in that regard.

Comment: Is 'static' needed at all here?

Comment: @Progrock It's not required, it's a micro-optimization when you don't need `$this` inside the closure.